# SQL server Update incompleto

Tags: sql-server

Estoy tratando de crear una tabla con campos editables y al final de la tabla que tenga un botón update, esta es mi sentencia al pasar el update (la tabla y el update lo trato de mantener lo mas simple posible ya que luego me cuesta trabajo ver que hice
:o ):

```
$query = "UPDATE usuarios SET 
                 incdia    ='$incdia1', 
                 pago             ='$pago1', 
                 sueldos          ='$sueldos1',
                 Pasajes             ='$pasajes1',  
                 dias_trabajados  ='$dias_trabajados1', 
                 dias_adicionales ='$dias_adicionales1'  
          WHERE Id_usuario = '$id' ";
```

estoy trabajando sobre SQL server y a pasado algo MUY rraro 
al correr mi Querry no me sale error actualiza los primeros 833 elementos pero después de hay no guarda nada ni actualiza nada

me parece extraño por que deja de funcionar a la mitad de la tabla y lo anterior lo hace perfectamente

tengo mas experiencia en phpmyadmin y es la primera ves que me enfrento a SQL server para una pagina , tendrá alguna restricción o algo donde pueda corregir?

Comment: ¿Qué valor tiene `$id`?. [edit] la pregunta con el código que está usando para ejecutar ese UPDATE; así como, si tiene errores, agréguelos a la pregunta.

Comment: Hola , en $id tengo $id = $_POST['Id_usuario'][$i]; y no me a marcado ningun error . enrealidad si hace su trabajo la aplicacion pero solo esta agregando los primeros 166 filas y no se por que deja de hacer el update apartir de ese punto :(

Comment: claus, entiendo, pero, ¿puede [edit] la pregunta agregando el fragmento código mas amplio? Ejemplo: Si estás usando un ciclo "for, while, do-while, etcétera" éste tiene algún problema al recorrer las filas.

Comment: hola mauricio , con muchisimo gusto!!!, como me a preocupado tanto este tema por mi trabajo resubi un porst en esat direccion https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/179866/sql-server-deja-de-insertar-registros-con-mi-instrucion-insert